# Taskmodule - How to get platform information in task module

Tags: html, asp.net-core, botframework, microsoft-teams

I was checking if there is a way we can detect the device type through which user is accessing task module.
As there is one requirement in our project where we need to show the content device specific i.e. different images for mobile device and different images for desktops/tabs.

The task module we are using is the custom form [HTML page].
Please suggest if there is a way to handle such scenario

Answer (score 0):

You can refer the following code to detect the device type through which user is accessing task module

```
microsoftTeams.getContext((context) => {
            setframeContext(context.frameContext);
            sethostClientType(context.hostClientType);
        });
```

Please find below sample link for your reference:https://github.com/OfficeDev/Microsoft-Teams-Samples/blob/main/samples/meeting-recruitment-app/csharp/MeetingApp/ClientApp/src/components/recruiting-details/recruiting-details.tsx